# How to customize context menu on Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm working in WatchKit 2.0. I want to customize my watch app's context menu based on state information in the corresponding iOS app. For example, if a process is running in the iOS app I want my context menu to have a "stop" menu item, and if the app is idle then I want the context menu to have "start new" and "continue previous" menu items.

From the watch side, is there a way to detect when the context menu is about to appear so I can poll the app to get state information and customize the menu items accordingly?

Failing that, what is the preferred approach? I suppose I could have the iOS app push state information to the watch whenever states change, but that would obviously fail if the watch wasn't on or in range.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've read more about the WatchConnectivity framework, I think the preferred approach is to use the  [`updateApplicationContext(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/updateApplicationContext:error:) function in the `WCSession` class to signal state changes. The watch will receive the state change at its earliest opportunity. That seems to be working reasonably well, at least in the simulator.